# How to concatenate a string as a pandas list to use with append PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, list

How can you append a value to many lists with slightly different names; Eg.
I have a list of the hours of the day: [1,2,3....,24], and I have 24 columns (Tables), where if the hour of the day equals one value, the value should be one, and in every other column it should be cero

```
`h1 = []
h2 = []
h3 = []
h4 = []
h5 = []
h6 = []
h7 = []
h8 = []
h9 = []
h10 = []
h11 = []
h12 = []
h13 = []
h14 = []
h15 = []
h16 = []
h17 = []
h18 = []
h19 = []
h20 = []
h21 = []
h22 = []
h23 = []
h24 = []
HourTable = []
Hour = 0
for i in range(0,len(dataset)):        
    Hour = Hora + 1
    HourTable.append(Hour)
    if Hour % 24 == 0:
        Hour = 0
```

` 
Basically I want something like

```
for h in range(0,len(dataset)):
if HourTable[h] == 1:
    h1.append(1)
    for hh in range(2,25):
        ('h'+str(hh)).append(0)  #THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

Where it would append a value of 0 to every table from 2 to 24.

How would one go around and do this?

Thank you!

Edit; What I want to accomplish in the end is to have a database with 24 columns where each column consists of one '1' and the rest of the columns are '0'

Comment: How about making a dictionary where keys are equal to h1, h2, h3... etc? You can't refer to variables like that.

Comment: I honestly think that you are approaching your goal in really wrong way -> you end up asking for really wrong solution. Try to give us context on what you actually want to accomplish. in your program.

Comment: If you had 10,000 columns, would you name `h1`, `h2`, `h3`... `h10000`? I would hope not.  You should create a `list` of `list` or a `dict` of `list` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I kindof managed a workaround for this, what I did was;

```
hours = {}
for i in range(1,25):
 hours["h"+str(i)] = []   
for n in range(0,len(dataset)):
 for qq in range(1,25):
     hours['h' + str(qq)].append(0)

hoursDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hours)

for nn in range(0,len(dataset)):
 hoursDF['h'+str(HoraTable[nn]%25)][nn] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an example following up on the comment above:

```
hours = {}
for i in range(1,25):
    hours["h"+str(i)] = []

for h in range(0,len(dataset)):
    if HourTable[h] == 1:
        hours["h1"].append(1)
        for hh in range(2,25):
            hours['h'+str(hh)].append(0) # This time it works!
```